# What is the matter with EdgeList[] of a directed graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Given:

```
dag1 = {"scst" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "sfin", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", 
   "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", 
   "sbus" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "sbus" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", 
   "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6"};
```

The following code intends to extract all the edges directed towards the vertex "sfin". However, it gives an empty set!

```
EdgeList[dag1, _ -> "sfin"]
```

Given a directed graph `dag1`, I like to extract the set of vertices having directed edges towards vertex "sfin", such as

```
{"sfin", "scst"}       for vertex "sfin"
{"bus", "stel", "ma6"} for vertex "sbus", etc.
```

Note that the vertex of interest is the first element in the above two example sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `EdgeList` you must use `DirectedEdge` instead of `Rule`

```
EdgeList[dag1, _ \[DirectedEdge] "sfin"]
```

[image]

```
EdgeList[dag1, _ \[DirectedEdge] "sfin" | "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] _]
```

[image]

Comment: Why? In the documentation, a directed arrow is used, which I replicated it. I got it. The shape of the arrow is slightly different!!!

Comment: The second part of my question is to construct the vertex sets as described in the question above. Can you also address to that?

Comment: @TugrulTemel VertexInComponent[dag1, "sfin"] or VertexOutComponent[dag1, "sbus", 1] ?

Comment: @halmir: VertexIn/Out components give a different result. I simply like to get the list of vertices having directed `In` links to a given vertex. Since the graph given `dag1` is a layered DAG, the result should be a list of vertices (acting as inputs) to a given vertex. I want to write the DAG as a set of functions, such as "sfin"=f["scst"] or "swhl"=f["scst", "sfin"] etc.